# Number of words in text you can fully type using this keyboard

Tags: python

There is such a task with [Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-number-of-words-you-can-type/description/). Everything works for me when I press RUN, but when I submit, it gives an error:

```py
text = "a b c d e"

brokenLetters = "abcde"
```

Output : 1

Expected: 0

```py
def canBeTypedWords(self, text, brokenLetters):
for i in brokenLetters:
    cnt = 0
    text = text.split()
    s1 = text[0]
    s2 = text[1]

    if i in s1 and i in s2:
        return 0
    else:
        cnt += 1
        return cnt
```

Can you please assist what I missed here?

Everything work exclude separate letters condition in a text.

Comment: If you're getting an error, please include the text of the error traceback with your question.

Comment: @JRiggles I did it. The first 6 lines  is the error

Comment: The implementation is completely broken. You only check the first two words and return from the function after you checked the first letter in `brokenLetters`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So consider *logically* what you have to do, then write that algorithmically.

Logically, you have a list of words, a list of broken letters, and you need to return the count of words that have none of those broken letters in them.

"None of those broken letters in them" is the important bit -- if even one broken letter is in the word, it's no good.

```py
def count_words(broken_letters, word_list) -> int:
    words = word_list.split()  # split on spaces
    broken_letters = set(broken_letters)  # we'll be doing membership checks
                                          # on this kind of a lot, so changing
                                          # it to a set is more performant
    count = 0
    for word in words:
        for letter in word:
            if letter in broken_letters:
                # this word doesn't work, so break out of the
                # "for letter in word" loop
                break
        else:
            # a for..else block is only entered if execution
            # falls off the bottom naturally, so in this case
            # the word works!
            count += 1

    return count
```

This can, of course, be written much more concisely and (one might argue) idiomatically, but it is less obvious to a novice how this code works. As exercise to the reader: see if you can understand how this code works and how you might modify it if the exercise was, instead, giving you all the letters that *work* rather than the letters that are *broken*.

```py
def count_words(broken_letters, word_list) -> int:
    words = word_list.split()
    broken_letters = set(broken_letters)
    return sum((1 for word in words if all(lett not in broken_letters for lett in word)))
```

Comment: I came up with `return sum(not any(letter in brokenLetters for letter in word) for word in text.split())`.

Comment: @Matthias: `sum(all(b not in word for b in broken_letters) for word in words)`

Comment: @gog Nice one, but I still can't decide which one makes the intention more clear.

Comment: @Matthias ah yes, implicit casts from bool to integer. I prefer aggregating them myself, but to each their own :). I also _mentally_ prefer `all(x not in y)` rather than `not any(x in y)` but only because my brain has to do gymnastics to grok the latter.